# python SQL SP with parameters is not working

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures

My code is running, but the SP is not actually excuting. When I run the printed `str1` directly in SQL Server, it works. I am playing with pyodbc:
It doesn't even go in the SP.

Code:

```
str1 = 'EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName="{filename}"'.format(filename="D:\\website\\1228file.txt",logid=1)
print(str1)
print('going to excute cursor')
cursor.execute(str1)
print ('Cursor executed')
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

I tried these varients also

str1 = "EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName='{filename}'".format(filename="D:\website\1228file.txt",logid=1)

str1 = 'EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName="{filename}"'.format(filename="D:\website\1228file.txt",logid=1)

str1 = "EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName='{filename}'".format(filename='D:\website\1228file.txt',logid=1)

str1 = "EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName='{filename}'".format(logid=1,filename='D:\website\1228file.txt.txt')

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping your single and double quotes.  The SQL statement itself likes single quotes,  so to acheive that make the outer quotes, doubles.  Python doesn't mind so much.

```
str1 = "EXEC dbo.spRunFile @logID={logid}, @fileName='{filename}'".format(filename='D:\\website\\1228file.txt',logid=1)
```

Comment: thank you mathew for your response Please chck updations